# All variants of string from array in PHP

Tags: php, string, text-parsing

I've got a string with spaces. I need to split (explode) it and got all variants of sequences from it. For example:

```
string1 string2 string3
```

I need to parse it and get an output like this:

```
string1 string2 string3
string1 string3 string2
string2 string1 string3
string2 string3 string1
string3 string2 string1
string3 string1 string2
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

EDIT: actually i need to parse maximum of 3 strings. So i'm doing this not a pretty way (hardcoded):

```
$exploded_query = explode(' ', $query);
if(count($exploded_query) == 2) {
//2 variants
}
if(count($exploded_query) == 3) {
//6 variants
}
```

So i'm looking for some pretty way to do it.

Comment: I think you should really be asking whatever question you're trying to answer with this approach. There's no *efficient way* to do this, because you have already stated that you need _every_ combination (the most efficient implementations of certain algorithms will intelligently pick which combinations they need to actually run - and they will short-circuit when possible). This means that the "most efficient" approach to this will still be n! (n factorial). Just 10 words is already 3 million combinations.

Comment: Do you have any code to post?

Comment: Yes, posted the code.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permutation of array

Look here -> [Finding All Permutations of an Array](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm), that's help you.

Answer (score 0):

By no means am I claiming this to be efficient or optimal. There are much better solutions out there. But this is just a direct answer to your question. If you want to remove some bloat (at the cost of likely a little bit of performance), you can replace the `getRemainingWords` function call with:

```
$index = 0;
array_values(array_filter($words, function($key, &$index) { return !($key == $index++); }));
```

Otherwise, here it is

```
function getPossibleCombinations($words) {
    $combinations = array();
    $count = count($words);

    // Base case: if there's only 1 word, there's only one combination
    if ($count == 1) {
        return array($words);
    }

    // Otherwise, loop over each words
    foreach ($words as $key=>$word) {

        // For each item, get all of the remaining items in the array (all except the current one)
        $otherWords = getRemainingWords($words, $key);

        // And recursively permute them
        $otherCombinations = getPossibleCombinations($otherWords);
        foreach ($otherCombinations as $otherCombination) {
            $combinations[] = array_merge(array($word), $otherCombination);
        }
    }

    return $combinations;
}


function getRemainingWords($array, $index) {
    $results = array();

    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        if ($key == $index) {
            continue;
        }

        $results[] = $value;
    }

    return $results;
}
```