# All combinations without repetitions with specific cardinality

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations

I have an array:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, ... , z]
```

and I would generate the set of all possible subarrays, withuout repetition, whose cardinality is between X and Y.

Let's assume php:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

$results = myFunction($array, 3, 5);
```

My function should returns something like:

```
array( 
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(1, 2, 4),
    ...
    array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
);
```

My attempt was to count in binary, from 0 to 2^n (where n is the cardinality of the set) and if the number of `1s` is between X and Y, add the array made of `1s` element to the result set.

Eg.

```
8  = 0000 0111 => add (6,7,8) to result
9  = 0000 1000 => no 
10 = 0000 1001 => no
...
```

but it's very ugly!
Any better algorithm?

I'm using php, but feel free to use whatever language you like.

Comment: You should use recursion.  Also be aware that the result set can be very large - that might be a good opportunity to learn about iterators.  (Yes, PHP supports that.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP array combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)

Comment: (use an outer loop from X to Y, or slightly more cleverly, adjust the recursion to yield partial results as long as X)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pretty straightforward solution (requires generators, I think, it's php 5.5+)

```
// generate combinations of size $m
function comb($m, $a) {
    if (!$m) {
        yield [];
        return;
    }
    if (!$a) {
        return;
    }
    $h = $a[0];
    $t = array_slice($a, 1);
    foreach(comb($m - 1, $t) as $c)
        yield array_merge([$h], $c);
    foreach(comb($m, $t) as $c)
        yield $c;
}
```

and then

```
$a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f', 'g'];

foreach(range(3, 5) as $n)
    foreach(comb($n, $a) as $c)
        echo join(' ', $c), "\n";
```

Comment: @marka.thore: you're welcome. Bear in mind though, this code is not particularly efficient.

Comment: you mean that generators are not efficient? How could be a more efficient way to do this (not the code, just the idea)?

Comment: @marka.thore: no idea about generators... but if performance matters, an iterative algorithm will be better than a recursive one. Search around for "generate combinations lexicographically".