# PHP Array permutation uniq ordered

Tags: php, arrays, permutation, uniq

### **TURNS OUT THAT MY MATH OPERATION WAS THE WRONG ONE! READ [PHP array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations) FOR AN EXAMPLE OF COMBINATION**

---

I Am searching the Web now for 3 weeks ( including SO) i dont find someone who has already asked or solved it.

I need a Permutation of an Array in PHP of only uniq **ordered** values.

`$array = array('Number1', 'Number2', 'Number3', 'Number4', 'Number5', 'Number6');`

usually a permutation will be like

`.1 Number1, Number2, Number3, ...;
.2 Number1, Number2, Number4, ...;
.3 Number2, Number4, Number1, ...;`

But i need it **ordered** and **uniq**. so the 3rd line would be ordered  to

`.1 Number1, Number2, Number3, ...;
.2 Number1, Number2, Number4, ...;
.3 Number1, Number2, Number4, ...;`

And that means Row 3 is NOT uniq and will not be saved in a new array.

2nd Example

`array('A','B','C')
A
AB
AC
ABC
ACB
B
BC
BA
BCA
BAC
C
CA
CB
CAB
CBA`

**is wrong for me**

I need the output like this

`A
B
C
AB
BC
AC
ABC`

I kinda solved it so far. BUT my solution is like **stoneage** and just sorts all new array_permutations and array_filter them. thats like 100 Years calculation time cause 6 numbers permutated with all possabilitys is like X^10 -.-

Please help me guys.

btw: its my first post here, so be gentle :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advise you to take a look the python module called [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).

It's a module for efficient looping and constains numerous operations involving permutations, combinatorics and more.

Despite being a module written in python language it shouldn't difficult to port the code to PHP language. However, since several of these operations may require considerable memory usage is a good idea to use **PHP 5.5+**, because in this version [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) were included.

- [PHP Generators overview](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)
- [itertools — Functions creating iterators for efficient looping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Comment: Ur answer kinda helped me :D
Cause i was looking for the WRONG mathematical operation.

What i need is "Combination" not "Permutation" that i could read out of ur links . so thx

because : permutations('ABCD', 2)   AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC  // but combinations('ABCD', 2)   AB AC AD BC BD CD

https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.