# Algorithm for creating all possible strings with x characters

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, while-loop, nested-loops

I can't wrap my head around the algorithm for making the following:

I have an array for all possible characters: `array("a", "b", "c",...."z", " ", "!"...)` you get the idea.

Now I would like to generate all possible compinations of these characters with the length of x.

so for example the `array("a", "b", "c")` with the length of 4: aaaa abaa acaa aaba aaca aaab aaac abba abca acba acca (....) baaa caaa

and so on...

Thanks in advice!

Comment: I believe those are technically "*permutations*" rather than combinations. https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with recursion:

```
COMBINATIONS(array, length):
    COMBINATIONS("", array, length)

COMBINATIONS(string, array, length):
    IF length == 0
        VISIT(string)
    ELSE
        FOR EACH c IN array
            COMBINATIONS(string + c, array, length - 1)
```

The basic idea is start with an empty string, then in each execution, call recursively for each character in the array. This will generate for each string previously generated a new string for each character in the array concatenated at the end.

When you reach the desired length then 'visit' the generated combination.

For example, for `array = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `length = 3`:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

Comment: thank you for answering..what do you mean with COMBINATION and VISIT? or what would be the php equivalent?

Comment: @3Descape: You're welcome. If the answer helps you please consider mark as accepted. Thanks

Comment: hmm.. just found that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations

Comment: @3Descape: This is pseudocode since you don't add any language tag, COMBINATIONS is just the name of the functions, with VISIT I means what you want to do with the generated combination (add it to a list, print in console)

Comment: yea I got that it is pseudocode, but what does this do? COMBINATIONS(array, length):
    COMBINATIONS("", array, length)

Comment: it's calling the other COMBINATIONS function below