# Get combinations of the string

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I am working on the dynamic reports here i want some combinations.Consider i have a `array('1,'2','3','4')` i want combinations as 1,2 1,3 1,4 but not like 1,2,3

Tried almost everything but not the solution.

Comment: so it's a simple loop. Try

Comment: Have a look on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array combinations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)

Comment: do you want each combination to be a string e.g. `1,2` OR an array like `array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        ), array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        ) ...` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will perfectly fine for the case when you are trying to `create combinations` of **2**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785258)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
$combinations = array();
foreach ($array as $key1 => $value1)
{
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        if ($value1 != $value2)
        {
            $combinations[] = $value1 . "," . $value2;
        }
    }
}
print_r($combinations);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2
    [1] => 1,3
    [2] => 1,4
    [3] => 2,1
    [4] => 2,3
    [5] => 2,4
    [6] => 3,1
    [7] => 3,2
    [8] => 3,4
    [9] => 4,1
    [10] => 4,2
    [11] => 4,3
)
```

Comment: Output match but i also want 2,1 2,3 2,4 upto 4,1 4,2 4,3

Comment: @varadmayee Thanks for accepting my post... :)