# empty array whenever it reaches a threshold

Tags: php, arrays, loops, combinations, bit

I have a loop that generates an array of all possible combinations of binary bits by giving the number of bits, but I encounter a memory issue when the number of bits exceeds **20**.

I'm looking for a way to remove or empty the previous array values for example if the array reaches 1k or 2k values, here's the code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= ($listN - 1); $i++) {
    $reverseBits = array_reverse($bits);

    $prefixBit = preg_filter('/^/', '0', $bits);

    $prefixReverseBits = preg_filter('/^/', '1', $reverseBits);

    $bits = array_merge($prefixBit, $prefixReverseBits);

    unset($prefixBit, $prefixReverseBits, $reverseBits);
}
```

I've tried this one but it does not work, the  `array` will be fully empty outside the loop:

```
if (count($bits) > 1000) {
    unset($bits);
    $bits = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code simply does nothing, if the `$bits` array is empty, because `array_reverse` and `preg_filter` do not modify the array size and `array_merge` only adds the existing numers together. So en empty array will always stay empty.

Instead set your "emtpy" array to the 1 bit default array `['0','1']`:

```
if(count($bits) > 1000){
    $bits = array('0','1');
}
```

In case you want to keep your "last 1000" results instead of deleting all reasults you got so far think about using `$bits = array_slice($bits, 0, 1000);` at the beginning of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving something like that, you simply have to do something of the sort:

```
if(count($bits) > 1000){
  $bits = array_slice($bits, 1000);
}
```

This will slice the array from the offset `1000` and leave the rest of the items of the array, intact.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I understand the practical use of your script, but you can do away with the temporary variables in your loop body.

`preg_filter()` is a suboptimal choice. `preg_filter()` is just like `preg_replace()` except `preg_filter()` has a destructive action after attempting to replace -- it removes all values which did not qualify for replacement. Because every string value will have a start position (even an empty string), this destructive step can never occur.  This means `preg_replace()` would be better.

But hold on, you are unconditionally pretending a character to each string in the arrays.  You don't need regex for that. `substr_replace()` can act on flat array data and is therefore the ideal function.

Here is my simplified script: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TWBBj))

```
$listN = 10;
$bits = [0, 1];

for ($i = 0; $i < $listN; ++$i) {
    printf("%d (%d): %s\n", $i, count($bits), json_encode($bits));
    $bits = array_merge(
        substr_replace($bits, '0', 0, 0),
        substr_replace(array_reverse($bits), '1', 0, 0)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
0 (2): [0,1]
1 (4): ["00","01","11","10"]
2 (8): ["000","001","011","010","110","111","101","100"]
3 (16): ["0000","0001","0011","0010","0110","0111","01 ...
4 (32): ["00000","00001","00011","00010","00110","0011 ...
5 (64): ["000000","000001","000011","000010","000110", ...
6 (128): ["0000000","0000001","0000011","0000010","0000 ...
7 (256): ["00000000","00000001","00000011","00000010"," ...
8 (512): ["000000000","000000001","000000011","00000001 ...
9 (1024): ["0000000000","0000000001","0000000011","00000 ...
```

Of course the `$bits` element count doubles upon each new iteration, so the magic number which breaks your script will depend on your memory settings.  Because each iteration relies on the full array of the previous iteration, slicing will only corrupt your output.  Increase your memory as needed.