# Nested loop with recursive function?

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, curl-multi

I need to do a recursive loop on every result suggested by google up to a user-defined depth and save results in a multidimensional array, explored later on.

I want to get this result.

```
google
google app
google app store
google app store games
google app store games free
google maps
google maps directions
google maps directions driving
google maps directions driving canada
...
```

Currently, my recursive function returns replicated results from the second nesting.

```
google
google app
google app
google app store
google app store
google app
google app store
google app store
google app store
...
```

I think the problem comes from the array (parent results) that I pass as an argument to my function recursive_function() to each nested loops.

```
$child = recursive_function($parent[0][1], $depth, $inc+1);
```

Recursive function

```
// keywords at line or spaced
$keywords = explode("\n", trim("facebook"));

$result = recursive_function($keywords, 2);

function recursive_function($query, $depth, $inc = 1)
{
    $urls = preg_filter('/^/', 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=', array_map('urlencode', $query));
            
    $parent = curl_multi_function($urls);

    array_multisort($parent[0][1]);
    
    if (count($parent[0][1]) === 0 || $inc >= $depth)
    {
        $out[] = $parent[0][1];
    }
    else
    {
        $child = recursive_function($parent[0][1], $depth, $inc+1);
        
        $out[] = $child;
    } 
        
    return $out;
}
```

Function curl

```
function curl_multi_function($data, $options = array()) 
{
    // array of curl handles
    $curly = array();
    
    // data to be returned
    $result = array();

    // multi handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    // loop through $data and create curl handles
    // then add them to the multi-handle
    foreach ($data as $id => $d) 
    {
        $curly[$id] = curl_init();

        $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        // post?
        if (is_array($d)) 
        {
            if (!empty($d['post'])) 
            {
                curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
                curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
            }
        }

        // extra options?
        if (!empty($options)) {
          curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
        }

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
    }

    // execute the handles
    $running = null;
    do 
    {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } 
    while($running > 0);

    // get content and remove handles
    foreach($curly as $id => $c) 
    {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        
        // decode json result
        $result[$id] = json_decode(utf8_encode($result[$id]));
        
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }

    // all done
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: So... What's the problem? Explain what input you have, what function should do with each depth element.

Comment: @Justinas : I have given more precision to my question. Sorry my english is no good.

Comment: Looks like `curl_multi_function()` returns many matrixes, but for some reason you only really care about the first one, this isn't compatible with what you expect as output, also I don't see any particular reason why the first suggestion would increment the query by just 1 word, my tests are indicating Google can suggest entire sentences just by entering one search term.

Comment: RecursiveIteratorIterator and getDepth() could help me?

Comment: You should try and narrow your quesion down to a single issue and give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems to me that you are firing a series of search requests at google, as your `curl_multi_function()` will be called again and again at every call of your `recursive_function()`. Is this really your intention?

Comment: @cars10m yes, the number of requests HTTP increases with each iteration and depth. I want to speed up the processing time by handling batch HTTP requests.

Comment: I don't find your question to be very clear, but I'd like to mention that your usage of `preg_filter()` can be replaced with `substr_replace($array, $url, 0, 0)` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78210669/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your recursive_function a little bit:

```
function recursive_function($query, $depth, $inc = 1)
{
    $urls = preg_filter('/^/', 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=', array_map('urlencode', $query));

    $parent = curl_multi_function($urls);

    foreach ($parent as $key => $value) {
      array_multisort($value[1]);

      $words = explode(' ', $value[0]);
      $lastWord = end($words);

      if (count($value[1]) === 0 || $inc >= $depth) {
          $out[$lastWord] = [];
      } else {
          unset($value[1][0]);
          $child = recursive_function($value[1], $depth, $inc+1);
          $out[$lastWord] = $child;
      } 
    }

    return $out;
}
```

It generates an array like this:

```
[
   google =>
     [
       app =>
         [
           store =>
             [
                games =>
                  [
                    free => []
                  ]
              ]
         ]
         ...
     ]
]
```

Is that what you want?