# Find unique (not repeating) combination php

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations

I'm facing a technical problem here, I have an array `[PER_DAY, PER_SIZE, PER_TYPE]`, I want to find combination all of the item without repeating the element, the result should be

```
    [PER_DAY]
    [PER_SIZE]
    [PER_TYPE]
    [PER_DAY, PER_SIZE]
    [PER_DAY, PER_TYPE]
    [PER_SIZE, PER_TYPE]
    [PER_DAY, PER_SIZE, PER_TYPE]
```

This code repeating same value, so the result is too much.

```
$arr = ['PER_DAY', 'PER_SIZE', 'PER_TYPE'];
$result = [];

function combinations($arr, $level, &$result, $curr=[]) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $new = array_merge($curr, array($arr[$i]));
        if($level == 1) {
            sort($new);
            if (!in_array($new, $result)) {
                $result[] = $new;          
            }
        } else {
            combinations($arr, $level - 1, $result, $new);
        }
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    combinations($arr, $i+1, $result);
}
```

This question possible duplicate, but I cannot found example similar like this, thanks.

Comment: But you have tried to code it yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)

Answer (score 1):

```
   function pc_array_power_set($array) {
    // initialize by adding the empty set
    $results = array(array( ));

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));

    return array_filter($results);
}
    $set = ['PER_DAY', 'PER_SIZE', 'PER_TYPE'];
    $power_set = pc_array_power_set($set);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($power_set);
```

You have make combination from array, will help you :-[PHP array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)

Comment: why we need to define $max, in my case, it should be length of $in right?

Comment: do you get your answer??