# How to get all ordered combinations without repetition between 6 of a set of numbers?

Tags: php

There is a set of **ordered** numbers , say `$nums = array(3, 7, 10, 12, 20, 24, 26, 34, 37);`

I want to get all the possible combinations of **6** numbers from the above array , and the **order** is from the lowest number to the greatest number; for example :

```
3, 7, 10, 12, 20, 24
3, 7, 10, 12, 20, 26
3, 7, 10, 12, 20, 34
3, 7, 10, 12, 20, 37
3, 7, 10, 12, 24, 26
3, 7, 10, 12, 24, 34
3, 7, 10, 12, 24, 37
3, 7, 10, 12, 26, 34
3, 7, 10, 12, 26, 37
3, 7, 10, 12, 34, 37
3, 7, 10, 20, 24, 26
3, 7, 10, 20, 24, 34
3, 7, 10, 20, 24, 37
3, 7, 10, 20, 26, 34
3, 7, 10, 20, 26, 37
3, 7, 10, 20, 34, 37
etc...
```

Comment: You must know that it was downvoted because you haven't started anything. Can you get the UNSORTED combinations? If you had the unsorted combinations, could you sort them?

Comment: I dont know how to achieve it ! I dont have any clue !

Comment: From the top of my head I'd probably start by working index-wise like [0,1,2,3,4,5] and then increment this as a "number" mod how many integers you have so it produces [0,1,2,3,4,6],...[0,1,2,3,4,8] and then [0,1,2,3,5,6] and so on.

Comment: This can be done with a pretty standard recursive algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations)

Comment: Google `permutations`

Comment: It's combinations, rather than permutations, as ordering does not matter.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - The OP is asking for "permutations" not "combinations", otherwise the OP would have included 3,7,10,12,24,20 in the output example. To the OP ... ordering does indeed matter.

Comment: @Kuya You've got that the wrong way round. [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) consider {1, 2, 3} to be distinct from {1, 3, 2}. Combinations do not.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need to work out the **factorial** of the length of the array, work it out like this:

```
function factorial($num){
    $factorial = 1;
    for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--) 
    {
        $factorial = $factorial * $x;
    }
}

$result = factorial(count($nums));
```

Comment: it gives the number of combinations ! What I want is the combinations ! you dont understand my needs !

Comment: Okay, no need to be like that, your question is worded very poorly. I'm only trying to help

Comment: please delete your answer

Comment: What is your problem? I was about to edit it and try and help you, but now forget it! P.s. leaving the answer here you baby

Comment: @LiamG - I am also looking for a solution to this problem. I have searched SO for hours. Some answers have come close, but they all inevitably output extraneous results. I would consider it a huge benefit to myself and to the SO community if you could go ahead and answer this question. Thanks